# How to implement solid border in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am building a new auto slideshow with rectangles down below. The thing I would like to implement is a black solid color that marked the colored rectangle, so visitors know which slide has been shown at that moment.

As you might see I have added style.border, but the black solid color does not follow the slide. When the 2e slide has been show the second rectangle should be marked with black solid color etc.

Anyone out there who knows how to solve this issue.

```js
var imagecount = 1;
var total = 4;
 function chgBubbleColorMiband(){
 var nodes = document.getElementById('bubbles-miband').getElementsByTagName("div");
 for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++){
 if (i == imagecount-1){
 nodes[i].style.borderColor = '#000000';
 }
 else {
 nodes[i].style.borderColor = 'transparent';
 }
 }
}

function slide(x){
 var Image = document.getElementById('imgmiband');
 imagecount = imagecount + x;
 if (imagecount > total){imagecount = 1;}
 if (imagecount < 1){ imagecount = total;}
 Image.src = "Img/miband"+ imagecount +".jpg";
 chgRectangleColorMiband();
}

window.setInterval(function slideA(x) {
var Image = document.getElementById('imgmiband');
if (imagecount > total){imagecount = 1;}
if (imagecount < 1) { imagecount = total;}
Image.src = "Img/miband"+ imagecount +".jpg";
chgRectangleColorMiband();
}, 5000);

function selectSlide(slideNumber){
 imagecount = slideNumber;
 var Image = document.getElementById('imgmiband')
 Image.src = "Img/miband"+imagecount +".jpg";
 chgRectangleColorMiband();
}
```

```css
@media (min-width: 767px){
#rectangle-miband{
 width: auto;
 margin: 0px auto;
 text-align: center;
 top: 90%;
 position: absolute;
 left: auto;
 height: auto;
 right: auto;
 display: block;
}
}

#rectangle-miband > div{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 14px;
 margin-top: 24px;
 margin-right: 14px;
 margin-left: 14px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 text-align: center;
 border-width: 1px ;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: transparent;
 font-size: 17px;
 transition: background 0.3s linear 0s;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="mi-band">
<img src="Img/miband1.jpg" alt="" id="imgmiband"/>

<div id="rectangle-miband">
<div onclick="selectSlide(1, this);" style="background:#4AB706;"></div>
<div onclick="selectSlide(2, this);" style="background:#FF52BD;"></div>
<div onclick="selectSlide(3, this);" style="background:#00B99F;"></div>
<div onclick="selectSlide(4, this);" style="background:#F86215;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had 2 typos!
4th line
getElementbyId -> getElementById

and
var Image = document.getElemenById('imgmiband') -> getElementById

Using Google Chrome's console to help debug your javascript, this should have been an easy one to catch ;).

```js
var imagecount = 1;
var total = 4;
 function chgRectangleColorMiband(){
 var nodes = document.getElementById('rectangle-miband').getElementsByTagName("div");
    console.log(nodes);
 for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++){
 if (i == imagecount-1){
 nodes[i].style.borderColor = '#000000';
 }
 else {
 nodes[i].style.borderColor = 'transparent';
 }
 }
}
 
function slide(x){
 var Image = document.getElementById('imgmiband');
 imagecount = imagecount + x;
 if (imagecount > total){imagecount = 1;}
 if (imagecount < 1){ imagecount = total;}
 Image.src = "Img/miband"+ imagecount +".jpg";
 chgRectangleColorMiband();
}

window.setInterval(function slideA(x) {
var Image = document.getElementById('imgmiband');
if (imagecount > total){imagecount = 1;}
if (imagecount < 1) { imagecount = total;}
Image.src = "Img/miband"+ imagecount +".jpg";
chgRectangleColorMiband();
}, 5000);

function selectSlide(slideNumber){
 imagecount = slideNumber;
 var Image = document.getElementById('imgmiband')
 Image.src = "Img/miband"+imagecount +".jpg";
 chgRectangleColorMiband();
}
```

```css
@media (min-width: 767px){
#rectangle-miband{
 width: auto;
 margin: 0px auto;
 text-align: center;
 top: 90%;
 position: absolute;
 left: auto;
 height: auto;
 right: auto;
 display: block;
}
}

#rectangle-miband > div{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 14px;
 margin-top: 24px;
 margin-right: 14px;
 margin-left: 14px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 font-size: 17px;
 transition: background 0.3s linear 0s;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="mi-band">
<img src="Img/miband1.jpg" alt="" id="imgmiband"/>

<div id="rectangle-miband">
<div onclick="selectSlide(1, this);" style="background:#4AB706;"></div>
<div onclick="selectSlide(2, this);" style="background:#FF52BD;"></div>
<div onclick="selectSlide(3, this);" style="background:#00B99F;"></div>
<div onclick="selectSlide(4, this);" style="background:#F86215;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your border in javascript this way:

```
nodes[i].style.border = "solid '#000000' 4px";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is OK except CSS part.
Try to change border definition from

```
   border: 1px solid transparent;
```

to :

```
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
```

this should helps. Before this change you simply overwrite border css properties.